# Property returns a different color id than the actual resource in a nested RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, properties, android-resources

I have a `RecyclerView.Adapter` that has a property for getting a color-id based on the `faded` flag. A similar code works with the parent adapter but here, with the nested one, I'm getting strage color ids. What am I doing wrong? This is not the first time I observe this effect. It happend with a [`Switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986180/cannot-get-switch-menu-item-because-r-id-is-different-from-menu-items-interna) too.

[image]

Comment: This absolutely doesn't make any sense. Why would this property return a different resource-id? Aren't they constants?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, AFAIK. Those `R.color` values aren't valid resource IDs. I've seen this before, too, but never have searched out why it's happening. Really seems like a bug. My code has always run as it should, though, despite the odd values in the debugger.